# Find a sequence of continuous functions that converges to a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, sequence-of-function

Let $f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
             0,  & x \leq 0 \\
             \\ 1, &   0 < x \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$

Find a sequence of $f_{n}$ such each one of $f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I think

$$f_{n}(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
             \frac{1}{n}x,  & x \leq 0 \\
             \\ x^{\frac{1}{n}}, &   0 < x \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
could work, Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this looks correct to me.

Comment: There are much simpler examples  $f_n(x)=0$, for $x\le 0$ and $f_n(x)=1$, for $x\ge \frac{1}{n}$ with $f_n(x)=nx$ for $0\lt x\lt \frac{1}{n}$.